# Takes very long for an image/video to be uploaded to my Amazon S3 media directory

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, digital-ocean

So I'm using Amazon S3 storage to store user-uploaded files. When a user makes a post on my Django website, it comes with some text and an image/video - that image/video gets uploaded to the `media` directory on my S3 bucket.

However this takes very long, e.g. including a 6mb image in the post will take the post over a minute to submit. If the image is small e.g. 150kb it will only take about 3 seconds for the post to submit. How can I improve this performance?

The `Post` is simply a form with the following fields (`image` is either an image or a video):

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.TextField(max_length=95)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
```

and the views:

```
def post(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        form_post = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form_post.is_valid():
            instance = form_post.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user

            instance.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
        else:
            form_post = PostForm()

        context = {
            'form_post': form_post,
        }

        return render(request, 'post/post.html', context)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/signup/")
```

Any idea?

Comment: Shrink the image file before the upload or increase the upstream of your server by upgrading to a more expensive contract.

Comment: Which column shows me the improved upstream performance?: https://i.imgur.com/RYY3P4D.png

Comment: None. It only shows the volume.

Comment: Looks like you are using DigitalOcean. You should tag DO questions appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to handle expensive, long-running operations like a file upload to S3 outside of the API endpoint handler.
It will make your web app more robust and scalable and you won't have to deal with log running HTTP requests that might time out and you can keep the user informed about what's going on.

You can use e.g. [Celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/) to handle the queuing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [django-queued-storage](http://django-queued-storage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which manages practical case of local/remote storage upload and retrieval.

a code sample from their doc for clarification.

```
from django.db import models
from queued_storage.backends import QueuedStorage
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

queued_s3storage = QueuedStorage(
    'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage',
    'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage')

class MyModel(models.Model):
    image = ImageField(storage=queued_s3storage)
```